# Create string from vector

Tags: python, r

I have a numeric vector. I want to enumerate over the vector and create a string as the result. For example, if I have a vector

```
x = c(1, 3)
```

I want the resulting string to be:

```
y = '1x1 + 3x2'
```

In Python, I would do this:

```
l = [1, 3]
equation = ' + '.join(['{}x{}'.format(coef, i + 1) for i, coef in enumerate(l)])
str = 'y = {}'.format(equation)
```

How can the same thing be done in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
x <- c(1, 3)
paste0(x, substitute(x), seq_along(x), collapse = " + ")
# [1] "1x1 + 3x2"
```

Explanation:

- Get object name: `substitute(x)` (this returns "x")
- Attach object name ("x") to `x` values and `x` index `seq_alon(x)` using `paste0()` with `collapse = " + "` argument.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Actually `substitute` goes beyond what was asked as I was expecting `x` to be a constant!

Comment: Why not simply `"x"`  instead of `substitute(x)`?

Comment: I overthought it. It might be used in some cases, but to answer OPs question its not needed.